# Why doesn't my included file render its contents to screen?

Tags: php

I want to use some php to make simple header/footer files for my webpages. I'm just getting started in web design and I am using Coffee Cup HTML Editor.

Problem is I have this line in my index.php file:

```
?php include(“includes/header.html”);?>
```

and nothing shows up even though my header.html file has a menu in it.

Do I need to install something on my machine before PHP code will show anything?

Comment: Those smartquotes sure look funny. Are you using smartquotes in your actual source or is that an artifact of some tool you used when creating this question?

Comment: Are you calling `echo` on your markup?

Comment: Well, do you have PHP installed? (http://php.net/manual/en/install.php) Any phpinfo page to prove it? error_reporting enabled? What do you see in view source?

Comment: I searched for how to install PHP, it led me to something called WiX...which I installed. But nothing happened with that. I thought I'd have to configure it with a webserver or something, even though I'm just working/testing locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Syntax errors

Firstly, your code snippet contains a syntax error. The opening PHP tag should be `<?php` and not `?php`. So your code should look like this:

```
<?php include('includes/header.html');?>
```

### Install PHP

Secondly, you need to run PHP scripts on a PHP server like [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) for the code to actually be executed.

This assumes header.html either contains text or if it is PHP it `echo()`s its output.

Comment: Also that has to the correct path to the file, if the php.ini on the server isn't set to show errors they will never see a file not found error for that file even if php really can't find it. since a file not found on a include() is not treated as a fatal error. (that's what require() is for)